# Complexity of a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I'm doing a project. I need to calculate the complexity of a recursive method. This method is called recursively and uses methods "incomingEdges" and "opposite". Can someone help me to find the complexity of "FUNCTION" method?

```
public HashMap<String, Integer[]> FUNCTION() {

    HashMap<String, Integer[]> times = new HashMap<>();
    Integer[] timesAct = new Integer[5];
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[graphPertCpm.numVertices()];

    Vertex<Activity, String> current = graphPertCpm.getVertex(0);
    timesAct[0] = 0;
    timesAct[1] = 0;
    times.put(current.getElement().getKeyId(), timesAct);
    FUNCTION(current, times, visited);

    return times;
}

private void FUNCTION(Vertex<Activity, String> current, HashMap<String, Integer[]> times, boolean[] visited) {

    if (times.get(current.getElement().getKeyId()) == null) {
        for (Edge<Activity, String> inc : graphPertCpm.incomingEdges(current)) {
            Vertex<Activity, String> vAdj = graphPertCpm.opposite(current, inc);
            FUNCTION(vAdj, times, visited);

        }
    }

    visited[current.getKey()] = true;
    for (Entry<Vertex<Activity, String>, Edge<Activity, String>> outs : current.getOutgoing().entrySet()) {
        if (!visited[outs.getKey().getKey()]) {
            int maxEF = 0;
            Vertex<Activity, String> vAdj = graphPertCpm.opposite(current, outs.getValue());
            for (Edge<Activity, String> inc : graphPertCpm.incomingEdges(outs.getKey())) {
                Integer[] timesAct = times.get(graphPertCpm.opposite(outs.getKey(), inc).getElement().getKeyId());
                if (timesAct == null) {
                    vAdj = graphPertCpm.opposite(vAdj, inc);
                    FUNCTION(vAdj, times, visited);
                } else {
                    if (timesAct[1] > maxEF) {
                        maxEF = timesAct[1];
                    }
                }
            }
            Integer[] timesAct = new Integer[5];
            timesAct[0] = maxEF;
            timesAct[1] = timesAct[0] + outs.getKey().getElement().getDuration();
            times.put(outs.getKey().getElement().getKeyId(), timesAct);
            if (visited[vAdj.getKey()] != true) {
                FUNCTION(vAdj, times, visited);
            }
        }
    }

    visited[current.getKey()] = false;
}
```

Opposite Method

```
  public Vertex<V, E> opposite(Vertex<V, E> vert, Edge<V, E> e) {

    if (e.getVDest() == vert) {
        return e.getVOrig();
    } else if (e.getVOrig() == vert) {
        return e.getVDest();
    }

    return null;
}
```

IncomingEdges Method

```
    public Iterable<Edge<V, E>> incomingEdges(Vertex<V, E> v) {

    Edge e;
    ArrayList<Edge<V, E>> edges = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numVert; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numVert; j++) {
                e = getEdge(getVertex(i), getVertex(j));
                if (e != null && e.getVDest() == v) {
                    edges.add(e);

                }
            }
        }


    return edges;
}
```

Comment: Think recursive algorithms, think [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: You've dumped quite a bit of code here, and few SO users will do a formal analysis.  I would recommend that you add logging statements to the various portions of each recursive call and then compare this output for different inputs.  You can build a graph this way empircally.

Comment: what have you done so far!?

Answer (score 1):

So, first are you familiar with the concepts of Big-O analysis?

The most common metric for calculating time complexity is Big O notation. This removes all constant factors so that the running time can be estimated in relation to N as N approaches infinity. In general you can think of it like this:

Constant O(1)

```
                                    statement;
```

The running time of the statement will not change in relation to N.

Linear O(n)

```
                        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
                            statement;
```

The running time of the loop is directly proportional to N. When N doubles, so does the running time.

Quadratic O(n2)

```
                       for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
                            for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
                                statement;
                        }
```

The running time of the two loops is proportional to the square of N. When N doubles, the running time increases by N * N.

Logarithmic O(log n)

```
while ( low <= high ) {
  mid = ( low + high ) / 2;
if ( target < list[mid] )
  high = mid - 1;
else if ( target > list[mid] )
  low = mid + 1;
else break;
}
```

The running time of the algorithm is proportional to the number of times N can be divided by 2. This is because the algorithm divides the working area in half with each iteration.

Linearithmic O(n log n)

```
                       void quicksort ( int list[], int left, int right ){
                            int pivot = partition ( list, left, right );
                            quicksort ( list, left, pivot - 1 );
                            quicksort ( list, pivot + 1, right );
                        }
```

Is N * log ( N ). The running time consists of N loops (iterative or recursive) that are logarithmic, thus the algorithm is a combination of linear and logarithmic (also termed linearithmic).

Note that none of this has taken into account best, average, and worst case measures. Each would have its own Big O notation. Also note that this is a VERY simplistic explanation. Big O is the most common, but it's also more complex that I've shown. There are also other notations such as big omega, little o, and big theta. You probably won't encounter them outside of an algorithm analysis course.

Your function can be stripped down to two `for-loops` with `recursive` calls and one additional `for-loop`:

```
 for (Edge<Activity, String> inc : graphPertCpm.incomingEdges(current)) {
            Vertex<Activity, String> vAdj = graphPertCpm.opposite(current, inc);
            FUNCTION(vAdj, times, visited);

for (Entry<Vertex<Activity, String>, Edge<Activity, String>> outs : current.getOutgoing().entrySet()) {

        for (Edge<Activity, String> inc : graphPertCpm.incomingEdges(outs.getKey())) {

                FUNCTION(vAdj, times, visited);
```

Then as suggested, consult the Master Theorem

[image]

If you need complexity of Graph Operations, Looking at the [Big-O Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) yields

[image]